# How to create a table by appending a string to a command line variable in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

Currently I'm using

```
    def PARAM1=&1
    def PARAM2=&2
    def PARAM3=&3
    DECLARE &PARAM4 VARCHAR(20);
    BEGIN
        PARAM4 := &PARAM1 || '2';
        CREATE TABLE &param4 AS SELECT * FROM &param1 Order By &param2,&param3;
    END;
    /
    exit;
```

I'm trying to run this but its giving me ar error as invalid SQL Statement.
I would call procedure from shell using SQLPlus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the anonymous PL/SQL block; within that you'd have to use `execute immediate` because you can't do DDL as a native command.

This is the equivalent of what you have I think:

```
def PARAM1=&1
def PARAM2=&2
def PARAM3=&3
def PARAM4=&PARAM1.2
CREATE TABLE &param4 AS SELECT * FROM &param1 Order By &param2,&param3;
exit;
```

The period between `&PARAM1` and the fixed value of `2` you're appending [marks the end of the variable name](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref458). Without it, `&PARAM12` would be interpreted as a new parameter. I'm guessing that might have been what was causing you a problem.

If I run that with parameters `t4`, `id`, `name` I get (with `set verify on`):

```
old:def PARAM1=&1
new:def PARAM1=t4
old:def PARAM2=&2
new:def PARAM2=id
old:def PARAM3=&3
new:def PARAM3=name
old:def PARAM4=&PARAM1.2
new:def PARAM4=t42
old:CREATE TABLE &param4 AS SELECT * FROM &param1 Order By &param2,&param3
new:CREATE TABLE t42 AS SELECT * FROM t4 Order By id,name
```

So the final statement it executes is:

```
CREATE TABLE t42 AS SELECT * FROM t4 Order By id,name
```

Or you can do the same thing without the explicit `define` commands:

```
CREATE TABLE &&1.2 AS SELECT * FROM &&1 Order By &&2,&&3;
exit;
```

The `order by` clause doesn't make much sense in a CTAS statement, since the data in the new table has no inherent order, but it's valid syntax.

---

If you really wanted to do it in an anonymous block, you'd have to just wrap that inside an `execute immediate`, but there would be no point unless you were planning some other logic around it:

```
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE &param1.2 AS SELECT * FROM '
      || ' &param1 Order By &param2,&param3';
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks it's working , but it executed the STAS statement twice(first it says table created then gives an error as table already exists) ,any idea why this could be happening ?

Comment: @David - did you have the semicolon on the end of the command, and still have the `/` on it's own on the next line? You don't need both. The `/` (re-)executes the command in the SQL*Plus buffer. (I put the `exit` back in the answer to show the `/` has gone).